# How IBM SPSS calculates exact p value for Pearson Chi-Square statistic?

Tags: spss, chi-squared

Usually, I use Fisher's exact test p value when the sample size is small for Pearson chi-square test. Then I realized that IBM SPSS reports exact p values for all the tests (i.e. Pearson Chi-Square, Likelihood ratio, Fisher's exact test, Linear-by-Linear association).

I especially wonder if anyone knows how IBM SPSS calculates exact p value for Pearson Chi-Square statistic (here p=0.042). I also realized Fisher's Exact Test has a test statistic value (here 6.143), which surprises me, since (as far as I know) this test calculates p value directly from the hypergeometric distribution.

I also read the IBM SPSS Exact Tests manual, but I'm still without a clue (http://www.sussex.ac.uk/its/pdfs/SPSS_Exact_Tests_21.pdf).

Any help would be appreciated.[image: hi-]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you request chi-square statistics in CROSSTABS for a 2x2 table, you also get the Fisher exact test, whether or not you have the Exact Tests module and request exact results in that dialog box (or the subcommand when using command syntax). That version provides only the exact one- and two-sided hypergeometric probabilities, computed by native SPSS Statistics code.

If you have the Exact Tests module, you have access to a much broader set of exact tests provided through code from Cytel, the makers of StatXact.

The value listed for the Fisher Exact Test (which is the Freeman-Halton extension of Fisher's test, sometimes referred to as the Fisher-Freeman-Halton test) is a transformation of the hypergeometric probability that is scaled to have an asymptotic chi-square distribution under the null hypothesis with (R-1)(C-1) degrees of freedom. The full formula can be found on page 139 of the following paper:

Mehta, C. R. (1994). The exact analysis of contingency tables in medical research. Statistical Methods in Medical Research, 3, 135-156.